# When should I do user interface work on the main thread while using Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I heard that I should always do user interface work on the main thread while reading data from Firebase.

I tried to do `self.tableView.reloadData` on the background thread inside a Firebase `observe(.value)` function and the app did not crash or freeze.

```
databaseReference.observe(.value) { [weak self] snapshot in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I tried to do the same work inside `getData` function instead of `observe(.value)` function and the app crashed.

```
databaseReference.getData { [weak self] error, snapshot in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

So why the app crashed inside `getData` function and it did not crash inside `observe(.value)` function?

[image]

Comment: While the Firebase SDK performs its network and other I/O on a background thread, it actually calls your callback on the main thread. If `getData` does not do that, it'd be a bug. Can you show the error you get? To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen https://imgur.com/a/Ymvu0RX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

While the Firebase SDK performs its network and other I/O on a background thread, it actually calls your callback on the main thread.

But it seems that `getData` does not do that here, which is a bug. So thanks for catching and reporting that.

I filed bug [#8245](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8245) on the Github repo, so check there for progress.

Answer (score 0):

UI updates (`tableView.reloadData`, for instance) must be done on the main thread only not dependant if Firebase or another third-party framework is used.

If you are not sure if a method of a third-party framework (as Firebase is) will execute its closure on the main thread you can check if you are on the main thread and dispatch execution onto it if needed.

For example, you can use this simple extension for `Thread` class to run any code that needs to be run on the main thread.

```
extension Thread {
    class func runOnMainThread(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            closure()
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: closure)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it inside Firebase completion handlers as following:

```
Thread.runOnMainThread {
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```